# Human Cell Atlas - Data availability

Tags: public-databases

A news item from 2017-10-18 on the website of the [Human Cell Atlas](https://www.humancellatlas.org/) states:

> In addition, the consortium today also announced the impending release of gene expression profiles from the first one million immune cells collected under the HCA, toward an initial milestone of collecting at least 30 million cells representing several tissues and organs for the atlas’ first draft. **These data, to be posted on an online repository by early November, will be freely available for researchers’ use**. (https://www.humancellatlas.org/news/14)

As of now, Feb 2018, I cannot find these data anywhere. 
Does anybody know where I can download the gene expression data of these 1 million immune cells or when it will be eventually published?

Comment: The preview version is [now available here](https://preview.data.humancellatlas.org/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is now [a post on Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/300431/):

> We are starting to define the release process for the Human Cell
>   Atlas.
>
> The first couple of HCA releases will be primarily single-cell RNA-Seq
>   and we are interested to know what you would expect our releases to
>   contain
>
> Please fill out our survey if you would like to help us define our
>   releases
>
> https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/S6Y753P

And I suppose that answers the original question: the data has not been released yet and probably won't be for a while considering they are still discussing how to make it available.

Update (from the same post):

> The first production release of the DCP is happening in June.
>
> The first data release of HCA is targetting Q4 2018.