# Human Cell Atlas - cell annotations

Tags: scrnaseq, public-databases

[Human Cell Atlas Preview Datasets](https://preview.data.humancellatlas.org/) have been available for a while now (there was some discussion about that [earlier](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/3541/human-cell-atlas-data-availability)). However, although the raw data is available, cell labels are not (for example, which cell type each cell belongs to). That seems like the most valuable part of this resource. I've heard of people using that type of information, but I have not been able to find it on the website. Is that available somewhere?

Comment: I only have peripheral knowledge of HCA so take this with healthy scepticism, but I believe that some aspects of the analysis pipelines for the project are still being finalised and harmonised, as there have been many new developments in the last year or so. It is possible that while some of those working on the data are using interim cell labels, the final labels have not been decided on thusfar.